# Read all function is only reading first entry of the list

Tags: python

This is supposed to give the whole file as its output but of the whole list it only gives the first entry, does anyone knows why ?

Here's the code for reference -

## Modules imported

```
import pickle
import os
import sys
```

## Assisting program

```
def countDigit(n):
    count = 0
    while n != 0:
        n //= 10
        count += 1
    return count
```

## To add a new account

```
def add(x="BankDatabase.txt"):
    file = open(x,"ab")
    Mrecord = []

    Account_number = int(input("Enter account number of the account holder - "))
    if countDigit(Account_number) > 20:
        sys.exit("Maximum 20 digits allowed!")                  
        
    Name = (input("Enter name of the account holder - "))
        
    Phone_number = int((input("Enter phone number of the account holder - ")))
    if countDigit(Phone_number) != 10:
        sys.exit("Invalid phone number!") 
        
    Address = input("Enter address of the account holder - ")
        
    Date_Of_Birth = input("Enter date of birth of account holder - ")
    if len(Date_Of_Birth) != 10:
        sys.exit("Invalid date of birth!") 
        
    Opening_Balance = int(input("Enter opening balance of the account  - "))

    Balance = Opening_Balance
        
        
    Trecord=[Account_number,Name,Phone_number,Address,Date_Of_Birth,Opening_Balance,Balance]
    Mrecord.append(Trecord)
    print(Trecord)
    pickle.dump(Mrecord,file)
    file.flush()
    file.close()
    print("Account added successfully !")
```

## To view the entire database (Not functioning block)

```
def viewall(x="BankDatabase.txt"):
    file = open(x,"rb")
    a = pickle.load(file)
    print(a)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pickle.load` unserializes the first object of the file. After reading it, if you call it again it will read the next object, and like that until the end of the file.

Just call it inside a loop and you will read all the objects.